# Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.card/event. Response ID: 0

Tags: flutter

Recently I was writing a card reading program. After the card reading process reached the card, I used EventChannel to send messages to Flutter. After I installed the apk, everything was normal, but the error occurred the next day.

The error message:

> Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.card/event. Response ID: 0

My java native code:

```
package com.test.handler.card;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.test.entity.ICard;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;

public class ICardEventCallHandler implements EventChannel.StreamHandler,EventSender{
private Object arguments;
private EventChannel.EventSink events;
  @Override
  public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
      this.arguments = arguments;
      this.events = events;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
      this.arguments = arguments;
  }

  @Override
  public void sendCard(ICard iCard) {
      String cardString = JSON.toJSONString(iCard);
      this.events.success(cardString);
  }
}
```

And:

```
package com.test.handler.card;

import com.test.entity.ICard;

public interface EventSender {
    void sendCard(ICard iCard);
}
```

My Dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
class ChannelHelper{
   static const eventChannel = const EventChannel("com.card/event");
   static void handleReadCard(void onData(dynamic event)){
     LoggerPrinter.info("listening card.");
     eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(onData);
   }
}
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22489.1000], 
locale zh-CN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Android Version: 5.1.1

Can someone help me, thanks！